# Mac OS X Debug Error

Tags: macos, gdb

On startup of my application with gdb, I am getting weird errors that look like:

```
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
```

The whole trace looks something like this:

```
[Session started at 2009-12-17 10:28:24 -0500.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-966) (Tue Mar 10 02:43:13 UTC 2009)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys003
Loading program into debugger…
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: Unable to read symbols for "@loader_path/../Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "Sparkle" (not yet mapped into memory).
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
Program loaded.
run
[Switching to process 9051 local thread 0x2e03]
Running…
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
```

I have tried every sort of analysis tool available, haven't been able to find any memory leaks or anything that could cause these unknown errors.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has a two part fix.

One make sure that you have Sparkle Copying in in the `Copy Frameworks` build phase.

Secondly, adding the following script as a buildphase after the `Copy Frameworks` helps fix the load path on some machines.

```
install_name_tool -change "@loader_path/../Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle" "@executable_path/../Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle" "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$EXECUTABLE_PATH"
```

Below is a screenshot of what this buildphase looks like in my project.

[Build Phase Example http://grab.by/1OkU](http://grab.by/1OkU)

And here is a screenshot of my target steps.

[Target Steps http://grab.by/1fCu](http://grab.by/1fCu)

Comment: Savior! I linked to an older version of Sparkle I have and problems went away. I will try this as well. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a slightly improved script which removes the need for manually adding your application name in the path: install_name_tool -change "@loader_path/../Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle" "@executable_path/../Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle" "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$EXECUTABLE_PATH". The script is from the Sparkle Q&A at https://answers.launchpad.net/sparkle/+question/46535

Comment: Updated the answer and screenshot.  Thanks Martin.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Worked for me when building a plugin for RapidWeaver :)